# require is not defined error in es6 export

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning to react and right now I am using React and React DOM from CDN instead of the node package.

This is my HTML File:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;500;700&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script
      crossorigin
      src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"
    ></script>
    <script
      crossorigin
      src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"
    ></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
  </head>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <body>
    <script type="text/babel" src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

in my index.js I have this code;

import Header from "./Header.js";
import MainComponent from "./MainComponent.js";
import Footer from "./Footer.js";

```
function Page() {
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
    </>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Page />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

and in my Header.js I have this as a code:

```
function Header() {
  return (
    <header>
      <nav className="nav">
        <img src="./images/logo.png" className="logo"></img>
        <ul className="nav-items">
          <li>Pricing</li>
          <li>About</li>
          <li>Contact</li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
  );
}

export default Header;
```

Both Header.js, index.html, and index.js are inside the same folder.

On running the index.html in server, i get this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at <anonymous>:3:15
    at ive (transformScriptTags.ts:99:10)
    at n (transformScriptTags.ts:173:9)
    at s (transformScriptTags.ts:204:11)
    at t.forEach.e.src.o.onreadystatechange (transformScriptTags.ts:121:9)
```

[image]

Can anyone help me, please !!

If anyone is curious, as to why I am doing this in CDN or not in a package or not in npx create react app, I am learning to react and want to learn thoroughly !!

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you using require somewhere in your import statements?

Comment: @OMGItsRob no, i have not

Comment: `<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>` this script contains `require` statements which throws errors in the browser. Try Browserify or Webpack or install babel using npm.